# how to add manual page break in tcpdf

Tags: php, css, pdf, tcpdf, html-to-pdf

Hai everyone iam trying to add manual page break in tcpdf i tried ,   but it doesn't works, how to break this..? in the location where i need to include coding

```
$content = '
                <style>
                    .chead
                    {
                    ...
                </style>

                <table class="body">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table style="width:595px;">
                                <tr>
                                    '.$myhead.'
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    //how to add manual page break here..?

                   <tcpdf method="AddPage" />

                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table style="width:595px;">
                                <tr>
                                    '.$mybody.'
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```php
<br pagebreak="true">
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this does't works for me :(            <tr>  
<td class="termhead">
<br pagebreak="true">
<b><u>Terms & Conditions&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:-</u></b>
</td>
</tr> i tried this and                                                                              <br pagebreak="true"><tr>  
<td class="termhead">
<b><u>Terms & Conditions&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:-</u></b>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: @PattatharasuN How You print Your `$content `? `writeHTML`, `writeHTMLCell`, `Write` e.t.c.? And what version of tcpdf You use?

Comment: iam using writeHTML and version 5.0.002

Comment: @PattatharasuN Try update Your tcpdf. I tested on `6.0.059` & it work fine with `writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '')`

Comment: Its a larger project @user3335966 , if i update have to change in many places, any how here i have changed my content into two different tables and fixed height for both of them as 1000px :)